# How to schedule a job(method) using Quartz.net in C#?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I want to schedule a simple job which adds a string to a listbox on a main form every minute. (I could use Timer, but let's say I have to stick to Quartz.net version 3) I looked at the manual and some tutorials and it seems a job should be a class.

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();

public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HelloJob is executing.");
    }
}
```

I looked up if a method(function) can be used as well, but I can't find any examples using a method instead of a class. Have I misunderstood it? I'd like to know if there's any way to schedule a method with Quartz.net.

Comment: 1) You have to schedule a class due to the interface requirement, and 2) this wouldn't work as you cannot update a WinForms Form from a completely different context

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto Thank you for your help. Could you please give me some advice and tell me if there is any library similar to apscheduler in Python which allows scheduling methods?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Why cannot you use System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto I'm making a program that connects to a server and receives time series data. The server disconnects sometiems and there are few jobs that need to be done at certain times, such as flushing, checking the connection, etc. My first goal is to check the latest data received time every minute and if it has been more than 30 seconds, I want the program to reconnect to the server(a method) and I thought I could check the time span with Quartz.net.